# Spark Cassandra Connector not adding all records to DB

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-zeppelin, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using version #: `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.11:2.0.0-M3`

I have a RDD from a kafka stream:

```
kafkaStream.foreachRDD((rdd: RDD[String]) => {
  if(rdd.count > 0) {
    println(java.time.LocalDateTime.now + ". Consumed: " + rdd.count() + " messages.");

    sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
                .select("count_metadata.tran_id")
                .write
                .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
                .options(Map("table" -> "tmp", "keyspace" -> "kspace"))
                .mode(SaveMode.Append)
                .save();
  } else {
      println(java.time.LocalDateTime.now + ". There are currently no messages on the topic that haven't been consumed.");
  }    
});
```

The RDD count is around 40K but the spark connector only populates the database with a consistent 457 records.

```
sqlContext.read.json(rdd).select("count_metadata.tran_id").count
```

also prints 40k records.

Here is my table statement:

```
cqlsh:kspace> CREATE TABLE tmp(tran_id text PRIMARY KEY);
```

The tran_id is unique for each message.

What am I missing? Why aren't all 40k records making it to that table?

My logs are not showing any exceptions either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The tran_id is unique for each message.

I lied:

```
println(df.distinct.count);
```

prints....

```
457
```

Time to bring it up to our upstream source.